# Debug method of logging package isn't working

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, logging, kivy

I have taken input from a form and passed them to this function from the kivy file (on_press property). The form data is fetched properly in the execute function but it won't get logged in myapp.log 
Here's the code:

```
import logging
import selenium

class UIf(GridLayout):
    def execute(self, *args):
        print("First probe")
        logging.basicConfig(filename="myapp.log", level = logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s:%(message)s')
        print("Second probe")
        for name in args:
            print("Third probe")
            logging.debug(name)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return UIf()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runapp = MyApp()
    runapp.run()
```

Comment: The logging code works fine by itself. If the args param is getting properly filled with string data then I'm not sure what the problem would be. Is there anything else we should know?

Comment: Are you sure what method `execute` has executed?
I can't see how you executed method in your sample code.

Comment: @gordlonious yes I had printed out(in console) all the arguments I passed from the kivy file after the "Submit" was pressed. All arguments are received properly as strings in the execute function.

Comment: @Zheka Koval Yep damn sure the execute function is being executed. I have created a simple form with kivy, taken user text from 4 fields, then after user hits the submit button, using on_press property execute function is executed, even the strings are received in the execute function I printed them out in console. The only problem is the strings won't get logged in the specified file.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to make your `basicConfig` call before importing any of kivy code, because it does its own, that could conflict with your parameters (especially output file).

Also, you might need to the debug level to DEBUG in kivy config, or to reset yourself the log level *after* the kivy import, because it reset it to its value.

I agree it's a bit intrusive and we should probably consider this a bug, though i don't know what the best way to both have good defaults and stay out of the way of people with opinions would be.

Comment: First and foremost thanks for the answer! I did try your solution but still it won't work. I shifted the logging basicConfig before I run my app. if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(filename="myapp.log", level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s:%(message)s')
    runapp = MyApp()
    runapp.run()

Comment: Ok now I actually placed the basicConfig right after the import statement of logging and all the other import statements after that, but it logs something else entirely and not the strings which I'm trying to log with logging.debug method. I'm really stuck with this..

Comment: I edited to add a part about log level, which could be your current issue.